# Combining multiple relation query in one - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 tables :- `items` and `groups`

`groups` table as below :-

```
create table groups (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
                     `group_name` varchar(255), 
                      primary key(`id`)
);
```

`items` table as follows :-

```
create table items (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
                    `group_for` int unsigned not null, 
                    `item_name` varchar(255), 
                     primary key(`id`), 
                     key `group_for` (`group_for`), 
                     constraint `fk_group_for` foreign key (`group_for`)                  
                     references `groups`(`id`)
```

I have below two eloquent method :-

```
class Item extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // No rules
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['group_for', 'item_name'];


    public function divGet() {
        return $this->belongsTo('group', 'group_for', 'id');
    }
}
```

Group eloquent

```
class Group extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // No Rules.
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['group_name'];

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany('item', 'group_for', 'id');
    }
}
```

Now, I am running below query :-

```
$groupItem = array()

// Fetching all group row
$gGroup = Group::all();

// Checking if there is not 0 records
if(!is_null($gGroup)) {

    // If there are more than 1 row. Run for each row
    foreach($gGroup as $g) {
        $groupItem[] = Group::find($g->id)->items;
    }
}
```

As you can see above, if i have 10 groups than , `Group::find.....->items` query will run 10 query. Can i combine them in 1 query for all more than 1 records of `Group::all()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), this will reduce your query operations into two queries.

Quoting the Laravel Eloquent docs, using your example:

> Your loop will execute 1 query to retrieve all of the Groups on the
>   table, then another query for each group to retrieve the items. So, if
>   we have 25 groups, this loop would run 26 queries: 1 for the original
>   group, and 25 additional queries to retrieve the items of each group.
>
> Thankfully, we can use eager loading to reduce this operation to just
>   2 queries. When querying, you may specify which relationships should
>   be eager loaded using the with method:

```
$groups = App\Group::with('Item')->get();
$groupItem = array();

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $groupItem[] = $group->items;
}
```

Comment: It didn't return group data like "group name", it only returned all "item list". I also want to have group data like "group name" with their item list..

Comment: Could you be more specific? This is doing the exact same thing as your code.  And the `$group` variable has your group data

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in my case, i have different scenario, 

i mean. group which has id - `1`, has name "`stackoverflow`" and has item `a`, `b` ,`c`. So it returns `a`, `b`, `c`, only, but it does not return , `group name` `stackoverflow` and it's `id` for which these items belongs to.

Receiving only `a`, `b`, as an array makes difficult understanding, which `id` or `group name` these lists belongs to. I hope, you got my point ???

in my query above, i can save another array of group data. But in your query, I am unable to get "group" data.

Comment: Just do this instead and forget the foreach `$groupItem = App\Group::with('Item')->get();`

Comment: oh my god! how can i miss that :) Great. Thanks a lot. I didn't notice, `$groupItem[0]->items[0]` and `$groupItem[0]` :) That's a lot of help brother. Thanks a lot.